# How to activate an object only when it's within the camera view

Tags: unity, c#

I want to toggle an object's active state using the camera view:

- when the object leaves the view it deactivates
- when the object enters the camera's view it activates

I'm using this to control the activity of objects in a carousel [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlu7HwYhaw4&feature=youtu.be)

I did this with a coroutine, but in my project the fps is falling a lot
because of the coroutine.

I've already used `OnBecameVisible` and `isVisible` but that's not it since they only work with a renderer.

```
    public void next() {
        StartCoroutine(On(waitnext));
    }

    IEnumerator On(float waitnext) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitnext);
        myArray[Selecao].SetActive(false);
        Selecao++;
        if(Selecao > myArray.Length - 1) {
            Selecao = 0;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitnext);
        myArray[Selecao].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void previous() {
        StartCoroutine(On2(waitprevious));
    }

    IEnumerator On2(float waitprevious) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitprevious);
        myArray[Selecao].SetActive(false);
        Selecao--;
        if(Selecao < 0) {
            Selecao = myArray.Length - 1;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitprevious);
        myArray[Selecao].SetActive(true);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the coroutine you're using at the moment? Also, in your example, it looks like the cubes have Renderer components, so why wouldn't OnBecameVisible would with those?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/8003/how-can-i-know-if-a-gameobject-is-seen-by-a-partic.html

Comment: 1-I used the cubes as the basis of my players
2-I use 2 transform before getting to my player for example
tranform 1 father, 2 pillar tranform, 3 my player, it would be better to disable the father who is more practical and fast

Comment: Look at [`GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes`](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html) and [`GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB`](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding colliders to your object and camera.

- preferably set the camera collider `isTrigger` on if the object is a rigid body.
- You can use tags, layers and game object name to filter which object you want to operate on.

Here is the code:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class FrustomColliderDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Gets called when it enters the camera collider
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "object-tag")
            other.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    //Gets called when it leaves the camera collider
    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision other) {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "object-tag")    
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: I even thought about using istrigger, but I do not know if this situation would work, would the collider have to be in the middle or at the edges of the camera view?

Comment: To have an accurate result, you have to align the collider with the view frustum which is probably a mesh collider, but you the box collider May work for you as well.

Comment: with certainty (oncollision and the trigger), does not work for my case because if I disable the gameobject it no longer has the reference to try to activate again